# Getting token access room forbidden Agora Whiteboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, agora.io, whiteboard

I am trying to integrate agora whiteboard in my website but getting this error.

```
[White] Error: connect failed: cannnot join room: token access room forbidden
```

if anyone know the solution please reply to this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.